# How can I clear individual validation errors?

Tags: javascript

I have an alert box that will pop up above my subscribe form, which indicates each specific input error in my form.

I wanted to know how I could get those errors to clear, one by one on keyup, if the input fields are then validated to my form's specifications? For example, a user comes by and hits send and nothing is filled out; there will be a list of errors. If then, the user decides to enter their name, but not their email address, the alert box should clear the text, "please enter your first name", but all other errors that haven't been corrected should remain.

I tried creating a function around the `<p>` tag within the error field, but I wasn't sure how to get around the valid variable within my script.

Here is the code that I have:

And a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cqf8guys/2/

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form #response2').hide();

$('.button2').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var valid = '';
var required = ' is required';
var first = $('form #first').val();
var last = $('form #last').val();
var city = $('form #city').val();
var email = $('form #email').val();
var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

if(first=='' || first.length<=1) {
    $('form #first').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #first').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your first name is required</p>';
}
else {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
}

if(last=='' || last.length<=1) {
    $('form #last').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #last').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
}
else {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
}

if(city=='' || city.length<=1) {
    $('form #city').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #city').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Please include your city</p>';
}
else {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
}

if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    valid += '<p>A valid E-Mail address is required</p>';
}

if (tempt != 'http://') {
    valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
}

if (tempt2 != '') {
    valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
}

if (valid != '') {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
        .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
}

else {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('processing2').html('<p style="top:0px; left:0px; text-align:center; line-height:1.5em;">Please wait while we process your information...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitFormSubscribe(formData);
}
});

});

function submitFormSubscribe(formData) {

$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: 'http://3elementsreview.com/blog/wp-content/themes/3elements/php-signup/sign-up-complete.php',
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 4000,
success: function(data) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error2' : 'success2')
          .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

if ($('form #response2').hasClass('success2')) {
setTimeout("$('form #response2').fadeOut('fast')", 6000);
}

},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
.html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
'</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
'</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
},
complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {                    
$('form')[0].reset();
}   
});

};
```

Comment: You do not want to click on subscribe to check for the errors. Thats why you want to go for key up on input. Is that what you are trying to tell?

Comment: Initially, when a user hits subscribe the form validates immediately for errors. I wanted to know how do I make each error clear individually when the alert box is up, when a user types in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**

```
<header class="main-hd">
    <h1 class="page-headline">Join 3Elements Review's email list</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <form class="contact-me" action="php-signup/sign-up-complete.php" method="post" name="contact-me">
        <div id="response2"><!-----------------CONTAINS FORM ERROR MESSAGE--------------></div>
        <input id="first" class='txt1' title="Your First Name is Required" maxlength="15" name="First" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input id="last" class='txt1' title="Your Last Name is Required" maxlength="15" name="Last" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input id="email" class='txt1' title="Your E-Mail Address is Required" maxlength="50" name="Email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\@\.com]{7,50}" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" />
        <input id="city" class='txt1' title="Please fill in your 'City'" maxlength="40" name="City" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{3,40}" type="text" placeholder="City" />
        <select id="country" name="Country">
            <option value="">Country</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
            <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        </select>
        <div id="ajaxLoader" style="display: none;">
            <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>
        <div id="cityAjax" style="display: none;">
            <select id="state" name="State">
                <option value="">-State/Region-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input id="tempt" name="tempt" type="hidden" value="http://" />
        <input id="tempt2" class="clear" name="tempt2" type="hidden" value="" />

        <button class="txt1 button2">SUBSCRIBE</button>

    </form>
</section>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form #response2').hide();

    $('.txt1').on('keyup click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = '';
        var required = ' is required';
        var first = $('form #first').val();
        var last = $('form #last').val();
        var city = $('form #city').val();
        var email = $('form #email').val();
        var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
        var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

        if(first=='' || first.length<=1) {
            $('form #first').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
            $('form #first').css('background-color','#ffcece');
            valid += '<p>Your first name is required</p>';
        }
        else {
            $('form #first').removeAttr('style');
        }

        if(last=='' || last.length<=1) {
            $('form #last').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
            $('form #last').css('background-color','#ffcece');
             valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        }

        if(city=='' || city.length<=1) {
            $('form #city').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
            $('form #city').css('background-color','#ffcece');
            valid += '<p>Please include your city</p>';
        }
        else {
            $('form #city').removeAttr('style');
        }

        if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
            valid += '<p>A valid E-Mail address is required</p>';
        }

        if (tempt != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
        }

        if (tempt2 != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (valid != '') {
            $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
            .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
        }else {
            if($('.button2').data('clicked')){
                $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('processing2').html('<p style="top:0px; left:0px; text-align:center; line-height:1.5em;">Please wait while we process your information...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

                var formData = $('form').serialize();
                submitFormSubscribe(formData);
            }
        }

    });

});

function submitFormSubscribe(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://3elementsreview.com/blog/wp-content/themes/3elements/php-signup/sign-up-complete.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 4000,
        success: function(data) {

            $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error2' : 'success2')
                .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

            if ($('form #response2').hasClass('success2')) {
                setTimeout("$('form #response2').fadeOut('fast')", 6000);
            }   
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
                .html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
                    '</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
                    '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {                    
            $('form')[0].reset();
        }   
    });
};
```

This should work!

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqf8guys/5/)

Comment: Rahul, the fiddle works, but I'm getting a syntax error as well.

Comment: Also, is there a way to keep the keyup functionality to keep validating in real-time, but not have the form process until you actually hit submit? Currently, the form submits as soon as correct information is placed into the input boxes. As well, when you first focus on any of the fields, the errors come up, which should only happen if the form is first submitted with out any info in the respective input boxes.